# Where I can find phpize for php7.1.1?

Tags: php7, xdebug

I currently installed `php7.0` version of phpize, and xdebug does not work, wondering if there is a phpize for php7.1.1?

Comment: how did you setup `xdebug`?

Comment: @George just followed the instructions here https://xdebug.org/wizard.php.

Comment: At what stage did you get stuck?

Comment: Did you add `xdebug.show_error_trace = 1` to the `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini` file

Comment: @George xdebug is not working because phpize is not compatible to my php version

Comment: @George there is no `xdebug.ini` in `mods-available` folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54795/discussion-between-george-and-dumb-question).

Answer (score 0):

To install `xdebug` for `php7.1`. Follow these steps to install for `php7.1`:

1. Install php7.1 dev, *if there go to step 2*:

   ```
   sudo apt install php-all-dev
   ```
2. Install the `xdebug` module:

   ```
   sudo apt install php-xdebug
   ```
3. Retstart `apache` with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
4. To test it:

   a. Go to the [page](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) you added to your OP and add the contents of your `phpinfo()` command to get the *relevant* `xdebug-2.5.1.tgz` file

   b. Follow the steps as directed on that page:

   1. `tar -xvzf xdebug-2.5.1.tgz`
   2. `cd xdebug-2.5.1/`
   3. now run `phpize7.1`, not `phpize` as given on that page

      - You should see this output, or something similar

        ```
        Configuring for:
        ...
        Zend Module Api No:      20151012
        Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
        ```
5. Add the following to the `/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` under any entry you see there:

   ```
   xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
   ```
6. Restart apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
7. Check your `phpinfo()` output on a webpage you should see the `xdebug` section now.

Comment: No, I am using php7.1.1 (when I installed xampp), xdebug does not work on it. that is my problem.

Comment: Then anywhere you see `php7.0` change it to `php7.1` and you should be good to go

Comment: What should I change? `phpize`?

Comment: There is also an error when installing the `php7.1` here it is `E: Unable to locate package php7.1-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-dev'`

Comment: I just updated the answer, use `php-all-dev` for the dev package for `php7.1

Comment: God, I cannot connect now to ubuntu's archive.

Comment: I think the server is down, so I can update it yet.

Comment: where I can find the contact email of ubuntu?

Comment: Is Ubuntu the one hosting the server?

Comment: No this is a desktop version, when I tried to do `sudo apt install php-all-dev` it seems that it can't connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: I have an error in your instruction 4.b) here is the error `No command 'phpize7.1' found, did you mean:
 Command 'phpize7.0' from package 'php7.0-dev' (main)
phpize7.1: command not found`

Comment: In `/usr/bin/` folder `phpize` version is 7.0, but I saw a folder `/opt/lampp/bin/` `phpize`'s version is 7.1.1. Can I just transfer it to `/usr/bin/` ?

Comment: please don't transfer  any thing leave as is. Please run `ls -l /opt/lampp/bin/phpize7.1.1` lets see if its symbolically linked to `/usr/bin/phpize`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54924/discussion-between-george-and-dumb-question).

Comment: Sir there is still a problem
In your instruction 4.b.3) now run phpize7.1, not phpize as given on that page
Here is the result
`No command 'phpize7.1' found, did you mean:
Command 'phpize7.0' from package 'php7.0-dev' (main)
phpize7.1: command not found`

Comment: Hello you say your having issues?

Comment: Yup in your instruction 4.b.3