# Can't install Xdebug (unmet dependencies: php7.1-dev > libssl-dev > libssl1.0.0)

Tags: package-management, php, dependencies, php7, xdebug

I'm trying to install Xdebug on Ubuntu Zesty (17.04), but am having trouble resolving dependencies. I'm following instructions from this url:

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Point 4. there says "Run: `phpize` (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize." When I do, I get the following error:

> The program 'phpize' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install php7.0-dev

I don't know why php7.0-dev is offered, my PHP version is 7.1. So instead, I tried installing php7.1-dev. Then I got this message:

> php7.1-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed

Finally, if I try installing libssl-dev manually, this is what I get:

> libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2g-1ubuntu11) but 1.0.2k-1+deb.sury.org~yakkety+1 is to be installed

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try my post https://askubuntu.com/questions/889367/where-i-can-find-phpize-for-php7-1-1/889493#889493

Comment: George when I run `sudo apt install php-all-dev`, I get: `php-all-dev : Depends: php5.6-dev but it is not going to be installed Depends: php7.0-dev but it is not going to be installed Depends: php7.1-dev but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f` then update your system and try again

Comment: Just did, same result. I believe the reason why I can't install php-all-dev is the same dependency issue from my question. Any idea how do I resolve it?

Comment: Well you have packages from a ppa for yakkety (openssl) that are higher versioned than the same in zesty's default repos ( and that ppa doesn't offer openssl for zesty). So either get rid of the yakkety packages or see what aptitude offers to do

Comment: Would you look at that! I somehow overlooked that libssl version says yakkety there. I've manually downgraded the libraries and everything went swell. Doug thank you very much for your comment. Would you please care to post a reply so I can accept it?